# Matrix of logarithmic mean

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis

I want to prove the matrix logarithmic mean in differential form.
$
L(A, B)^{-1}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(t A+B)^{-1}}{t+1} d t
$
for positive definite matrices $A, B$.

I know $L(A, B)^{-1}=\frac{\log A-\log B}{A-B}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(A+t)(B+t)} d t$

and use the property $(A+t T)^{-1}=A^{-1 / 2}\left(I+t A^{-1 / 2} T A^{-1 / 2}\right)^{-1} A^{-1 / 2}$  to expand the two equations.

However, I cannot prove the equation.  Could everyone give some other hints to solve the problem?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you agree that your formula $\frac{\log A-\log B}{A-B}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(A+t)(B+t)} d t$ is only meaningful if $A,B \in \mathbb{R^+}$ (it is ill-defined if $A,B$ are matrices because division by a matrix is ambiguous.)

Comment: A nice article dealing with matrix means in general: https://indico.ictp.it/event/a12193/material/0/0.pdf One of the authors (R. Bathia) is famous and I recommend you his book "Positive Definite Matrices"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!!!